# Code using .address not executing code, though it runs without error

Tags: vba, excel

I can not figure out what is missing from the `Sub RemoveC`

The function works fine as I can call it for a single column but I want to run it on entire sheets and `address` is pretty fast

The code runs but nothing happens , not sure what I need to change so that my use of `.address` works

Thanks

```
Sub RemoveC()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets(Array("X", "Y"))
    With ws.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)

       removeChars " & .Address & "

    End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

Function:

```
Function removeChars(ByVal strSource As String) As String
Dim strResult As String
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Len(strSource)
    Select Case Asc(Mid(strSource, i, 1))
        Case 0, 9, 10, 12, 33, 48 To 57, 126 To 255:

        Case Else:
            strResult = strResult & Mid(strSource, i, 1)

    End Select
Next i

removeChars = strResult

End Function
```

Comment: You are applying `removeChars` to a string literal and then discarding the result -- so what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @JohnColeman Why do you say that Tim is discarding the result? As far as I can tell the function is returning back the original string without the "forbidden" characters `0, 9, 10, 12, 33, 48 To 57, 126 To 255`.

Comment: Yes, I am doing exactly as @Ralph  is saying

Comment: @Ralph The call `removeChars " & .Address & "` doesn't *do* anything with the return value and the function itself (since it is `byVal`) has no side effects on the passed string. Furthermore, `" & .Address & "`  is a literal string which doesn't change from worksheet to worksheet.

Comment: I was tring to use `.addess` to apply the function `removeChars` to every cell in the worksheets

Comment: If you are trying to apply `removeChars` to the **content** inside each cell of the, change `removeChars " & .Address & "` to `.Value = removeChars(.Text)`

Comment: @scottholtzmanThank you!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Scott, post your comments as the answer and I'll upvote it. You're doing a great job, Sir. My best,

Comment: @Tim - I am posting as answer since it seems to be that. Please mark accordingly so that others know going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to have the function apply to the **content** of the cell, change `removeChars " & .Address & "` to `.Value = removeChars(.Text)`